# Where is the iOS App Bundle in an react-native project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bundle

I'm trying to upload my App to [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) to test it out. I found the other apps we have uploaded on [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) (/MyApps) and want to upload my app using the `+` on the left.

My options are

- New App
- New macOS App
- New iOS App Bundle

and I choose the 3rd option (new iOS App Bundle).

Where is my iOS App Bundle in a react-native project?

I have multiple targets. Is it just the target folder in Xcode (doesn't appear so)?

And how do I add it to my App Store Connect? I've been drag+dropping random folders from Xcode and my `.xcodeproj` file and none are sticking.

Comment: You archived and uploaded it in Xcode already?